# Can Frobenius Method start with the ∑ starting from 1?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

So, the terms I obtained was 0 for the whole series as the 1st term I obtained was also 0. However,  when the question was done with ∑ starting with 0, it gives a nice series of answer. So, does that mean that solving Frobenius method should start with the ∑ of 1 and not any other integer?
The Differential Equation for the question is :
xy"+(1+x)y'+ny=0

Comment: Are you sure your DE is of the right form? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method

Comment: It's not clear what your summand is. If you mean that you've obtained a solution of the form $c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + \ldots \,$, then there is some issue with how you apply the Frobenius method, as $y = 0$ is the only such solution.